# How to display the charts as coverflow in fusioncharts?

Tags: fusioncharts, coverflow

I am using Fusion Charts to display the chart, is it possible that I can display all the existing charts as a coverflow, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use clone() method provided by FusionCharts API to achieve that. You can refer to FusionCharts Developer's Documentation for more details: [Example](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/advanced-chart-configurations/drill-down/set-chart-as-hotspot.html#creating-a-thumbnail-of-the-chart) | [clone() Method](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods.html#clone)

Comment: Hello, sikrigagan, thanks for reply. But my question is displaying all my charts as a coverflow or carousel.

Comment: @JoyceGuo There is no such way to generate coverflow or carousel directly, you can specify clone() method for each and every chart and create thumbnails for each of them which can be displayed in coverflow created.

Comment: Thanks sikrigagan. Finally I used [Jquery Coverflow JS](http://vanderlee.github.io/coverflow/) to resolved my issues.